# How do I loop a statement in c++

Tags: c++, loops

I want to loop a question and make it say  "press Y to continue or N to quit" but I don't quite know how. I tried to do a while loop but they haven't worked well. Here's the code:

```
    cout << "press Y to play again or anything else to close: ";
    cin >> val;

    if (val != "Y" && val != "y")
    {
        spelaIgen = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best for you to use cases to make your selections of "Y or N". The attempt you were making would have made it so any character other than Y would quit.

```
bool correctVal = false;
char val;

while (!correctVal)
{
    cout << "press Y to play again or N to close: ";
    cin >> val;
        switch(val)
        {
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                spelaIgen = false;
                correctVal = true;
                break;
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                spelaIgen = true;
                correctVal = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "\nInvalid entry!" << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks worked, do you have a guide on how to use the case and break btw

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/ is a pretty good resource for understanding the use of switch, I think of it as the switch identifies the variable the case identifies the value, break will move you out of the switch and default is used almost like an else statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the standard namespace in C++ here. Try the following:

```
string val = "Y";

while (val == "Y")
{
    cout << "press Y to play again or anything else to close: ";
    cin >> val;

    if (val != "J" && val != "j")
    {
        spelaIgen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is using C++, use `std::string`, `std::transform` and `std::tolower`.  No reason to revert back the C-Style strings.

Comment: I'll try it in a second, but is there a way to put a choice that, press Y to play again or N to quit? @LawrenceAiello

Comment: Better.  I suggest using `std::transform` and `std::tolower` to convert the text to all lower case so you only need to perform `if (val != "j")`.  By converting the text to all upper or all lower case you remove the need for the second comparison.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews alright, do I just type somewhere, std:: transform?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Initialize your input variable, then use that variable as your `while` condition. Continue iterating your `while` loop until they enter something other than `'y'` or `'Y'`.

```
char val = 'Y';
while (val == 'Y' || val == 'y')
{
    // Do stuff

    cout << "press Y to play again or anything else to close: ";
    cin >> val;
}
```

Comment: hmm alright I'll try this too but as I asked LawrenceAiello, is there a way to put a choice that, press Y to play again or N to quit?

Comment: Sure, but what do you want to do if they enter neither `y` nor `n`, for example if they type `a`?

Comment: looks nicer, or something there's exact reason to that